# Transposition Cipher returning wrong results

Tags: encryption, vim, python-2.6

This is the source code I got from https://inventwithpython.com/hacking

```
import math, pyperclip

def main():
    myMessage = 'Cenoonommstmme oo snnio. s s c'
    myKey = 8

    plaintext = decryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    print(plaintext + '|')
    pyperclip.copy(plaintext)

def decryptMessage(key, message):
    numOfColumns = math.ceil(len(message) / key)
    numOfRows = key
    numOfShadedBoxes = (numOfColumns * numOfRows) - len(message)

    plaintext = [''] * int(numOfColumns)

    col = 0
    row = 0

    for symbol in message:
        plaintext[col] += symbol
        col += 1 


        if (col == numOfColumns) or (col == numOfColumns - 1 and row >= numOfRows - numOfShadedBoxes):
            col = 0
            row += 1

    return ''.join(plaintext)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What this Should be returning is 
`Common sence is not so common.|`

What im getting back is
`Coosmosi seomteonos nnmm  n. c|`

I cant figure out where the code is failing to send back the phrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is OK.  The problem is that you're using the wrong version of Python.  As the 'Installation' chapter of that website says:

> Important Note! Be sure to install Python 3, and not Python 2. The
>   programs in this book use Python 3, and you’ll get errors if you try
>   to run them with Python 2. It is so important, I am adding a cartoon
>   penguin telling you to install Python 3 so that you do not miss this
>   message:

You are using Python 2 to run the program.

The result is incorrect because the program depends on a feature that behaves differently in Python 2 than in Python 3.  Specifically, dividing two integers in Python 3 produces a floating-point result but in Python 2 it produces a rounded-down integer result.  So this expression:

> (len(message) / key)

produces 3.75 in Python 3 but produces 3 in Python 2, and therefore this expression:

> math.ceil(len(message) / key)

produces 4 (3.75 rounded up is 4) in Python 3 but produces 3 (3 rounded up is 3) in Python 2.  This means that your `numOfColumns` is incorrect and therefore the decryption procedure produces an incorrect result.

You can fix this specific issue by changing `(len(message) / key)` to `(float(len(message)) / key)` to force Python 2 to treat that calculation as a floating-point division that will give the desired 3.75 result.  But the real solution is to switch to using Python 3, because these differences in behaviour between Python 3 and Python 2 are just going to keep causing trouble as you proceed through the rest of the book.